# Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ado.net

Please note that presently I am attempting to execute the following INSERT command via C# ADO.NET, but am receiving the above error:

```
INSERT INTO tblStampAnnotation ([StampAnnotationID],[Title],[Subject],[Content],[Author],[Date],[LinkedDocumentsID],[PageNumber],[Colour]) VALUES('{6b15a625-b967-4d3b-9ee3-34f64633f469}','test title','test subject','test content','test author',GETDATE(),'{475f30a1-142f-4fd5-b783-598d838559de}',1,Null)
```

Found a small program to check if GUID is correct here:  http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18293

When I run the program, it indicates that both the {6b15a625-b967-4d3b-9ee3-34f64633f469} and {475f30a1-142f-4fd5-b783-598d838559de} are GUIDs.  Does anyone have any suggestions to determine why I am receiving this error?  TIA.

UPDATE:

Thank you for the suggestion, bobs; however, when I use the following command I still get the same error:

```
INSERT INTO tblStampAnnotation ([StampAnnotationID],[Title],[Subject],[Content],[Author],[Date],[LinkedDocumentsID],[PageNumber],[Colour]) VALUES('6b15a625-b967-4d3b-9ee3-34f64633f469','test title','test subject','test content','test author',GETDATE(),'475f30a1-142f-4fd5-b783-598d838559de',1,Null)
```

UPDATE 2:
Please note that I am using SQL Server 2008.

UPDATE 3:
This is getting strange.  I still receive the same error when I use NEWID():

```
INSERT INTO tblStampAnnotation ([StampAnnotationID],[Title],[Subject],[Content],[Author],[Date],[LinkedDocumentsID],[PageNumber],[Colour]) VALUES(NEWID(),'test title','test subject','test content','test author',GETDATE(),NEWID(),1,Null)
```

Comment: I have successfully inserted your strings in table in SQL Server 2012. I am not able to test on SQL Server 2008 unfortunately. Could you try to convert the string before inserting it into the table? Also could you try to use NEWID() instead the string?

Comment: I was able to test on 2008 and it inserts just fine.

Comment: Thank you gotqn--I tried using NEWID() as you suggested, but still receive the error.  Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that I had copied this table over from another database using the right-click on database -> Tasks... ->  Import Data and then I got the uniqueidentifier error.  To solve the problem, I deleted the table, and re-created it using the "New Table..." designer, and after I tried the same first INSERT command it worked fine, so something weird happened when I copied it over using import.  Thank you everyone for your suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

You should remove the braces {} from the GUID value.

```
'6b15a625-b967-4d3b-9ee3-34f64633f469'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, bobs; however, I removed the braces, and that did not solve the problem.  Please see the answer I posted.